# Understanding how a sequence works

Tags: scheme, lisp, fold, sicp, accumulate

I have the following `accumulate` function:

```
; accumulate
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence) (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))
```

I'm trying to write a `length` function to get the length of a sequence using the `accumulate` function.

For the function to plug into `accumulate`, why is it `(+ y 1)` instead of `(+ x 1)` ? That's the part I can't figure out:

```
(define (length sequence)
  (accumulate (lambda (x y) (+ x 1)) ; wrong
              0
              sequence))

(define (length sequence)
  (accumulate (lambda (x y) (+ y 1)) ; correct
              0
              sequence))
```

Comment: with proper indentation you would see it right away yourself. [pay attention to types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67777254/849891), what goes were. see `list?` and the discussion around it in that answer.

Comment: @tf3 ah yes you've put the finger on it. it _is_ supposed to be all pretty self-evident and clear as we go. if it's not, it means the reader needs to go back and re-read until it is! also watching the videos should be helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `x` and `y` doesn't tell you anything what it is. However if you look at `accumulate` you can see how `op` is called:

```
(op (car sequence)                          ; first argument is the element
    (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence))) ; second argument is the accumulated value
```

While it doesn't really look that way Imagine that the second argument is calling `accumulate` on the empty sequence. Then you get this:

```
(op (car sequence)
    initial)
```

So lets make `length`:

```
(define (length sequence)
  (accumulate (lambda (element initial) 
                ;; initial is often also called acc / accumulator
                (+ 1 initial)) 
              0
              sequence))
```

So the answer is that the first argument is the individual element while the second is either the initial value (`0`) or the previous calculated value which is `0` with as many `1` added as the tail of the sequence had. Thus a number. WHy you don't use the first argument is that you can't really use `"a"` or whatever the list contains to count elements since you need to just count them not use them as values. If you use the first argument and it happens to be strings what is `(+ "a" 0)` supposed to help in finding out that the list has length `1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `(lambda (x y) (+ x 1))` as `op`, then your `length` (or to be precise, the `accumulate`) function will *not use* the result of the recursive calls to the `accumulate` function. It will essentially only do one computation, `(+ x 1)` ,where `x` is `(car sequence)`, the first element of `sequence` -- and this one computation *may or may not even make sense*, depending on whether or not `x` is a number, and even if it did the answer would be wrong.

On the other hand, if `op` is `(lambda (x y) (+ y 1))`, then your function will replace

```
(op (car sequence) (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))
```

with

```
(+ (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)) 1)
```

The recursion bottoms out with the computation `(+ 0 1)`, so you ultimately get the length of the list, when each of the nested recursive calls to accumulate return the length of the sub-lists to their calling functions.